# Octal Calculator with Primality check

Tags: code-golf, number

## Problem

Build an octal calculator that can do the following operations:

- Add (+)
- Subtract (-)
- Multiply (*)
- Divide (/)
- Check is prime

Counting in octal is like this with decimal

```
(Octal)  (Decimal)
0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        6 
7        7
10       8
11       9
```

and so on...

So given input `a` `b` `c`

- `a` being a number in octal
- `b` being an operator (+, -, *, /) not is prime
- `c` being a number in octal

Output the expression evaluated as `abc = Output (Is prime)`

Test cases:

`a=3, b='+', c=3 -> 6 (false)`

`a=5, b='+', c=5 -> 12 (false)`

`a=1, b='*', c=5 -> 5 (true)`

`a=7, b='+', c=6 -> 15 (true)`

`a=31, b='-', c=11 -> 20 (false)`

`a=25, b='/', c=3 -> 7 (true)`

## Rules:

- The output just needs to contain the answer and a truthy/falsey value of whether it is prime so `[4,0]` is fine.
- The inputs will always be a case that outputs an integer (integer division)
- This is code golf so shortest answer wins

[When is an octal number a prime](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214093725/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55880.html)

Comment: Can we do something like `[12, 0]` or `[4, 1]` instead of `12 (false)` and `4 (true)`?

Comment: Yes, will ammend.

Comment: ...as if being octal is a property of numbers...

Comment: Can we get lists of octal digits?

Comment: Also, does division refer to integer division?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Lets say `a` `b` and the answer will always be an integer

Comment: @LeakyNun It isn't but using them in code should atleast prove a challenge. Don't you agree.

Comment: @LiefdeWen Oh so I can assume integer division. What about an octal digit list?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Added

Comment: @LiefdeWen Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62455/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-liefdewen).

Comment: @totallyhuman, you have to take 3 seperate strings though.

Comment: What should the primality test output on 1? Should it even be defined behavior?

Comment: One isn't a prime, and it is defined behavior for the case `2/1`

Comment: But 1 isn't composite either.

Comment: @totallyhuman I don't understand?

Comment: @totallyhuman `1` is generally understood to not be a prime number. The definition of a prime number is `exactly two positive divisors, 1 and the number itself`. `1` only has 1 positive divisor, so it is not prime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Definition_and_examples see also https://oeis.org/A000040

Comment: Please provide examples for the other operations, especially the prime test.

Comment: @Titus I've added test cases for multiply and division, as for prime test, the prime test is always done at the end.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 38 bytes

```
{a=#@@(#~FromDigits~8&)/@#2,PrimeQ@a}&
```

Anonymous function. Takes input in the form `... &[Plus, {"7", "12"}]` (with both numbers as octal strings and the operator being `Plus`, `Subtract`, `Times`, or `Divide`) and returns output in the form `{17, True}` (with the number in decimal.) Did this based on my own, possibly incorrect, interpretation of the rules; please comment if I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

```
‚8ö`³.VDps8B‚
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMsi8PbEg5t1gtzKSi2cALy//834zI24NIGAA)

Input format:

```
c
a
b
```

Output format:

```
[Is prime, 'Output']
```

Note that strings and numbers are equivalent datatypes in 05AB1E.

Comment: Hmm...not sure if valid.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I don't think it'd behave correctly (also there's `ð` for `' `), since the operator is designed to work on base-10 ints, while it would have incorrect results with base-8 ints. Also you aren't supposed to check if the base-8 version is prime, but the integer itself before converting to base-8 with `8B`.

Comment: No it still makes the operator work on the base-8 versions of the integers (something it's not supposed to do). Basically it would treat them as base-10 integers.

Comment: Back to disliking the challenge, get it now though.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 82 bytes

```
(a,b,c,k=m=eval((v=0)+a+b+v+c))=>{while(k-->3)m%k||(v=1);return[m.toString(8),!v]}
```

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rt1mzcf/)

Input is in octal base, output is also in octal base.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>89</s> 67 bytes

*A whopping -22 bytes thanks to suggestions by Rod.*

```python
n=eval(''.join(input()))
print[oct(n),all(n%i for i in range(2,n))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcQ9CoQwEAbQfk8xzTIzEkSFLfckYhHEn5HwJYQoePqIr3jpLnvEUCv@y@WDMLdHNIghnUVU9ZOyoYxxLgJ1PgTB12iNmYwMlD22RQYH1anWkbueHXHz1v14egA)

Takes input as:

```python
['01', '*', '05']
```

Prints a list like:

```python
['05', True]
```

Comment: You can drop both `lambda`s switching to `input()/print` to save 2 bytes, also since you are using `eval`, you don't need to convert to `int(,8)`, you can use octa literals in the string to save 10+

Comment: 1 is shown prime you need to add `x>1and` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Dḅ8jVµb8V,ÆP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4Y5Wi6ywQ1uTLMJ0DrcF/P//P9rYQEfBLPb/4e0A)

Uses `×` for `*` and `÷` or `:` for `/` (approved by OP in chat).

Argument 1:

```
[a, c]
```

Argument 2:

```
b
```

Output:

```
[Output, Is prime]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 104 bytes

```php
for(eval("\$i=\$n=octdec($argv[1])$argv[2]octdec($argv[3])|0;");--$i>1&&$n%$i;);echo
decoct($n),_,$i==1;
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7901d3f1259fa63b8ae3296bb032bf8eb6fad64).

Output format: `Result_1` for primes; `Result_` for non-primes.

Output for negative results is faulty; replace the `echo` part with `echo$n<0?-decoct(-$n):decoct($n),_,$i==1;` (+17 bytes) to fix.